# Script adding alias in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have written this thing, but it is not working. I do not know why. The script does not create any alias. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ans=t

while [ $ans == y ]; do
    echo "Give alias name"
    read name
    echo "Give aliast instruction"
    read instruction
    echo "alias $name='$instruction'" 
    read ans
done
```

That is probably simple question, I am totally new to Linux.

Comment: Don't link images.
Put your script lines in the text. You can format the lines script with the stackoverflow editor

Comment: i can't add pictures in other way yet

Comment: Don't put images or link to images.
Put your script.

Comment: oh, okay, i will try

Comment: i have changed it

Comment: you never get into the while loop: `$ans` is not "y"

Comment: @glennjackman's comment is true, and you do not do anything related to alias in that code, so I guess you just wanted to solve that part of your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"==" isn't for test equal. It is a simple equal: "="
For check if it is different it is: !=

For define an alias you must use the command alias.

And you must execute the script with the command:

```
. ./script
```

The first dot is important if not the script will be executed by a sub-shell and the alias definition will be for the sub-shell, and not the actual shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
ans=t

while [ $ans != y ]; do
    echo "Give alias name"
    read name
    echo "Give aliast instruction"
    read instruction
    alias "$name=$instruction" 
    read ans
done
```

Comment: I am sorry, that I answer that lately, but I really forgot. But you helped me a lot. The script was accually working, the only problem was with the way I was excuting it. Using . ./script solved the problem. Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

In unix derived systems, it is irregulary to have a process (child) alter the environment of the process that created it (parent).  This is a sharp contrast with windows, which historically had no notion of processes.  Windows, especially its command environment, owes its execution model to a 1970s system called *CP/M* which it was cloned from.

In windows, a `batch` file can alter the current shell's environment; for example, `cd /temp` would change the current directory of the shell.   In unix derived systems this is not true.  A child cannot alter the parent's environment [ of course there is an exception, below ]; so any files opened, closed, directories changed, environment variables set/reset, etc... all only affect the child.

So, while you might be able to have a script containing ```
alias bye=logout
``
that alias would only exist in the script.

The exception is a concept of *sourcing*.   A unix shell typically has a command called `source` (abbreviated `.`, as in `. myscript.sh`), which rather than creating a new process to run *myscript.sh* in, merely includes *myscript.sh* in the current shell.

With *source*, you can achieve the effect you need, after tidying up your errors mentioned in the comments.   In the meantime, you should be able to source something like this ```
alias bob="I need, I need, I need"

```
and verify that it works.
```